# Regex for PHP seems simple but is killing me

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a replace in a string with a regex, and I really hope the community can help me.

I have this string :

```
031,02a,009,a,aaa,AZ,AZE,02B,975,135
```

And my goal is to remove **the opposite** of this regex

```
[09][0-9]{2}|[09][0-9][A-Za-z]
```

i.e.

```
a,aaa,AZ,AZE,135
```

(to see it in action : http://regexr.com?3795f )

My final goal is to `preg_replace` the first string to only get

```
031,02a,009,02B,975
```

(to see it in action : http://regexr.com?3795f )

I'm open to all solution, but I admit that I really like to make this work with a `preg_replace` if it's possible (It became something like a personnal challenge)

Thanks for all help !

Comment: Why not explode the string on comma, filter it based on the regexp, and implode the result?

Comment: Do you want to retain all tokens which begin with a 0 or 9 and strip everything else?

Comment: There is no particular reason that this should be simple.  Regular expressions are not closed under negations.  You can do it by playing around with negative lookahead/lookahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Taemyr pointed out in comments, my previous solution (using a lookbehind assertion) was incorrect, as it would consume 3 characters at a time even while substrings weren't always 3 characters.

Let's use a lookahead assertion instead to get around this:

```
'/(^|,)(?![09][0-9]{2}|[09][0-9][A-Za-z])[^,]*/'
```

The above matches the beginning of the string or a comma, then checks that what follows does *not* match one of the two forms you've specified to *keep*, and given that this condition passes, matches as many non-comma characters as possible.

However, this is identical to @anubhava's solution, meaning it has the same weakness, in that it can leave a leading comma in some cases. See [this Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/oHtx9J).

`ltrim`ing the comma is the clean way to go there, but then again, if you were looking for the "clean way to go," you wouldn't be trying to use a single `preg_replace` to begin with, right? Your question is whether it's possible to do this without using any other PHP functions.

The anwer is yes. We can take

```
'/(^|,)foo/'
```

and *distribute* the alternation,

```
'/^foo|,foo/'
```

so that we can tack on the extra comma we wish to capture *only in the first case*, *i.e.*

```
'/^foo,|,foo/'
```

That's going to be one *hairy* expression when we substitute `foo` with our actual regex, isn't it. Thankfully, PHP supports [recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php), so that we can rewrite the above as

```
'/^(foo),|,(?1)/'
```

And there you have it. Substituting `foo` for what it is, we get

```
'/^((?![09][0-9]{2}|[09][0-9][A-Za-z])[^,]*),|,(?1)/'
```

which indeed works, as shown in [this second Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/kpQQQ5).

---

Let's take some time here to simplify your expression, though. `[0-9]` is equivalent to `\d`, and you can use case-insensitive matching by adding `/i`, like so:

```
'/^((?![09]\d{2}|[09]\d[a-z])[^,]*),|,(?1)/i'
```

You might even compact the inner alternation:

```
'/^((?![09]\d(\d|[a-z]))[^,]*),|,(?1)/i'
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning look-behind assertions. I don't yet know if it helps OP.

Comment: In OP text your regexps will match ,a,aa.  Thus consuming one comma too much.

Comment: @Taemyr - I meant "either of the two to exclude," or "neither of the two to include," so I think I did mean "either" in this case, but thanks for the heads up! I definitely mix up those words sometimes. I'm not sure I agree about my regex excluding one comma too much, though. Can you explain how?

Comment: @Taemyr - You're right. Edited to "neither." Any thoughts on the extra comma? I think removing two commas in ",a,aa" is appropriate, except at the beginning, which is why I've put `^` first, to short-circuit.

Comment: The problem is that when you match ",a,aa" you will not match ",aaa".  So replacing all will leave you with "031,02a,009aaAZE,02B,975,135".  I think you will need to do variable length matches and negative lookahead rather than lookbehind.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your very instructional post ! I didn't know anything about « look-behind », but I agree with @Taemyr, what we have here doesn't work :(

Comment: @Taemyr - Thanks for all your insightful comments. You should be the one getting points. Kai23, I've rewritten my entire solution. Please have a look. The demo is at http://ideone.com/kpQQQ5.

Comment: Sorry, there is one more subtle flaw remaining. So I think you should go for `/^(foo)(,(?1))*,|,(?1)/`. Problematic string: `'xxx,abc,031'`

Answer (score 1):

Try it in more steps:

```
$newList = array();
foreach (explode(',', $list) as $element) {
  if (!preg_match('/[09][0-9]{2}|[09][0-9][A-Za-z]/', $element) {
    $newList[] = $element;
  }
}
$list = implode(',', $newList);
```

You still have your regex, see! Personnal challenge completed.

Comment: I think @Geoffrey Bachelet's solution is a little shorter, but thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try matching what you want to keep and then joining it with commas:

```
preg_match_all('/[09][0-9]{2}|[09][0-9][A-Za-z]/', $input, $matches);
$result = implode(',', $matches);
```

The problem you'll be facing with `preg_replace` is the extra-commas you'll have to strip, cause you don't just want to remove `aaa`, you actually want to remove `aaa,` or `,aaa`. Now what when you have things to remove both at the beginning and at the end of the string? You can't just say "I'll just strip the comma before", because that might lead to an extra comma at the beginning of the string, and vice-versa. So basically, unless you want to mess with lookaheads and/or lookbehinds, you'd better do this in two steps.

Comment: I like your underated solution, even if it doesn't only work with regex. Will keep it if not other way

Comment: I'm a big fan of regexes, but sometimes you have to keep things simple and readable :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$s = '031,02a,009,a,aaa,AZ,AZE,02B,975,135';
echo ltrim(preg_replace('/(^|,)(?![09][0-9]{2}|[09][0-9][A-Za-z])[^,]+/', '', $s), ',');
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
031,02a,009,02B,975
```

Comment: This will leave a leading comma when something needs to be removed at the beginning of the string (example: `zzz,031,02a,009,a,aaa,AZ,AZE,02B,975,135`). You could use ltrim to fix that.

Comment: +1 - My original answer was wrong, and @anubhava's was the closest to correct. I've edited my answer to make it possible to do without `ltrim` (a silly but interesting challenge).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/(^|,)[1-8a-z][^,]*/i', '', $string);
```

this will remove all substrings starting with the start of the string or a comma, followed by a non allowed first character, up to but excluding the following comma.

As per @GeoffreyBachelet suggestion, to remove residual commas, you should do:

```
trim(preg_replace('/(^|,)[1-8a-z][^,]*/i', '', $string), ',');
```

Comment: This will leave a leading comma when something needs to be removed at the beginning of the string. You could use `ltrim` to fix that.

Comment: @GeoffreyBachelet can you make an example for that? It shouldn't leave leading commas.

Comment: `preg_replace('/(^|,)[1-8a-z][^,]*/i', '', 'zzz,031,02a,009,a,aaa,AZ,AZE,02B,975,135');` returns `,031,02a,009,02B,975`